# how changes in gridview are reflected in database ? technically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

like answers should be technical, i know the code to fill and update grid view and other controls but i actually don't know precisely that how it does ?

like i change row in GRID VIEW and click update, it changes(updates) data in database too, some says that Adapter do this but even in my update code (OnRowUpdate Event) doesn't have any object of SQ L Adapter so how come ?

I am using Asp.net(C#).

e.g.

```
protected void gvTest_RowUpdating(Object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) 
{
    int index = e.RowIndex;
    TextBox txtBoxName = (TextBox)gvTest.Rows[index].FindControl("txtboxTest");
    int pk = Convert.ToInt32(gvTest.DataKeys[index].Value);
    //Response.Write("Index_update="+ pk);

    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(constrng);
    SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("update login set name= @name where stid=@pk",sqlCon);
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBoxName.Text;
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pk", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pk;

    try
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connectToDb();
        Response.Write("<br/>" + "UPDATE STATEMENT=DONE");

    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Response.Write("<br/>"+ ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlCon.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems pretty straightforward.  When a row is being updated, it triggers the `RowUpdating` event, which this method handles.  In this method...

You get the values from the row being updated in the UI:

```
int index = e.RowIndex;
TextBox txtBoxName = (TextBox)gvTest.Rows[index].FindControl("txtboxTest");
int pk = Convert.ToInt32(gvTest.DataKeys[index].Value);
```

You define your SQL connection and command to execute an `UPDATE` statement in the database:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(constrng);
SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("update login set name= @name where stid=@pk",sqlCon);
sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBoxName.Text;
sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pk", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pk;
```

You run the command against the database:

```
sqlCon.Open();
sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now, there are *better* ways to structure all of this.  (Of course, there are almost always better ways to do just about anything.)  But in an ideal scenario what this code is doing is pretty clear.

Comment: no no sir, what i mean is that:
Some say that SqldataAdapter is a bridge between database and dataset,  so in what cases taht bridge helps ? even in this scenario too ?

Comment: @Hunain: A `SqlDataAdapter` is *one* way (one of many) for code to provide updates to a database.  This code isn't using one, it's using a `SqlCommand` instead.  You can probably use a `SqlDataAdapter` if you want, there are tons of examples online.  Though depending on other code we haven't seen here it may be overkill for this scenario.